# Convert UnsafeMutableRawPointer to UInt64

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swift4

I have an instance of UnsafeMutableRawPointer and want to retrieve intenger representation of it. I'm trying to use the following code:

```
let pointer : UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = address(of: self)
let intRepresentation : UInt64 = UInt64(bitPattern: pointer)
```

But Swift compiler throws error: "Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer?' to expected argument type 'Int64'"

Constructor declared as `public init(bitPattern pointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)` is Swift.Math.Integers.UInt
Also it has `public init(bitPattern x: Int64)` in the same file

How I can make this code work or convert UnsafeMutableRawPointer to integer in any other (but not too ridiculous, like string parsing) way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(U)Int` has the size of a pointer on all platforms (32 bit or 64 bit), so you can always convert between `Unsafe(Mutable)(Raw)Pointer` and `Int` or `UInt`:

```
let pointer: UnsafeRawPointer? = ...
let intRepresentation = UInt(bitPattern: pointer) 
let ptrRepresentation = UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: intRepresentation)
assert(ptrRepresentation == pointer)
```

Your code

```
let intRepresentation = UInt64(bitPattern: pointer)
```

does not compile because `UInt64` does *not* have an initializer taking a pointer argument, and that is because pointers can be 32 bit or 64 bit. (And even on a 64-bit platform, `UInt` and `UInt64` are distinct types.)

If you need an `UInt64` then

```
let intRepresentation = UInt64(bitPattern:Int64(Int(bitPattern: pointer)))
```

does the trick.

Comment: What happens if pointer exceeds Int type? It silently truncates value or throws some kind of exception?

Int(bitPattern: ...) looks good enough for me, I'm doing return `Int(truncatingIfNeeded: intRepresentation)` on next line anyway

Comment: Ok, it never exceeds Int:


/// On 32-bit platforms, `Int` is the same size as `Int32`, and

/// on 64-bit platforms, `Int` is the same size as `Int64`.

Comment: @Krypt: `Int` has always the same size as a pointer, but `Int` does not necessarily have the same size as `Int64`.

Comment: Well, the only unresolved mystery is why original code fails to compile?

Comment: @Krypt: `Int` (and also `UInt` as I just noticed) have an initializer taking a pointer argument. But `UInt64` does not have such an initializer. Even if UInt and UInt64  have the same size, they are different types.